VSCode's debugger command is splitting into several incomplete commands, making it impossible to connect to
I'm using VSCode's Debug & Run feature, and I'm running Python code. For some reason, the command that it's using to actually run the program is malformed, and hence doesn't actually start a debugging instance:

(another example):

It's supposed to be doing this:

But somehow the command seems to be getting cut in two. I don't entirely know how to manually start this process, so I'm getting blocked as I can't start debugging instances. What's going on here? I know filenames aren't too long as this exact configuration worked merely a couple hours ago.
I am using the default run configuration, if that helps. The issue here isn't the filename, it's the fact that the full command (that I don't have control over) is malformed. I can't even manually start the correct command and attach it to the VSCode debugger, because it launches a random 5-digit (port? I assume) number that I can't change in time.
If I had to theorise, it just seems like there's some text in the buffer from the last set of commands, and it's just outputting those as a tail end of the correct command. I have zero clue why this is happening, and why retrying the run doesn't just clear this, but how do I even go about fixing this?

Please don't post text as images. Use a code block instead.

ah, these aren't meant to be actual copyable text though; these are just generated commands given by vscode to illustrate the reason why the failures are happening
